# click Save button in File Download IE, when system is locked

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, download, autoit

I am using AutoIt to handle windows objects in Selenium scripts. I am facing a challenge in clicking "Save" button in "File Download" pop up, while downloading a file from Internet explorer.

I use `ControlFocus` statement to get the focus to the "Save" button, and used `ControlSend` to send `ENTER` or `ControlClick`  to click the button.

Both of these ways works fine when the system is not locked, but fails when the system in unlocked.

Note: I observed that the focus is getting shifted to "Save" button, however for some reason the button is not getting clicked. I tried the same to click "cancel" button and it works fine.

Kindly let me know, if there is any way/work around to click on "Save" button and that would work when the system is locked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my code where even i got to the las stage but it wasn't saving, I realized the focus was still on the website and not on the save as dialogue box,

steps to follow.

1. change the focus to save as dialogue box
2. follow the code below in autoit

   `//WinActivate("Save As") //ControlFocus("Save As","","Button2") //Send("{ENTER}")`